# How to avoid multiple mapper calls when using flatMapSingle

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

Suppose I have a `BehaviorProcessor` which contains some value `v`.

Now if I want to asynchronously request some data, which would depend on `v` I would do it like this:

```
val res = v.flatMapSingle { asyncRequest(it) }
```

Now let's log all the invocations of this block (mapper)

```
val res = v.flatMapSingle {
    println("mapper")
    asyncRequest(it)
}
```

It will print `mapper` multiple times, which means `asyncRequest` is being called multiple times, it seems every time some other dependant stream is being `subscribe`d to

I am trying to avoid multiple mapper invocations (thus avoiding multiple `asyncRequest` calls).

Is there a way to do so with standard rxjava2 utils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cache()` operator. It will cache result of `flatMapSingle`.

```
BehaviorProcessor<String> v = BehaviorProcessor.create();
Flowable<String> res = v.flatMapSingle(item -> {
    System.out.println("mapper");
    return asyncRequest(item);
    })
        .cache();
v.onNext("test");
res.subscribe(s->System.out.println("subscribe1 received: "+ s));
res.subscribe(s->System.out.println("subscribe2 received: "+ s));
v.onNext("test2");
```

Produces

```
mapper
mapper
subscribe1 received: test async
subscribe2 received: test async
subscribe1 received: test2 async
subscribe2 received: test2 async
```